# WPF - Update Main Window from different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Usually when someone wants to do some long running task and report its progress to the UI, the long running task is called in a new thread while the UI is updated.
I wanted the do a more comfortable approach, something like:

```
MainWindow.SetWatingMsg("please wait ...");

doLongRunnnigTask();

MainWindow.RemoveWaitingMsg();
```

So in this case the UI should be updated in a different thread from the one the long running task is running.
I have tried this in this, in my main window I have a hidden viewbox with an animation of a progressbar. In my App I have a reference to my main window, so my plan was to have the following functions that I could call from different place in my code:

```
public void SetWaitMsg(string msg)
{
    if (Session.User != null)
        if (Session.User.Configuration.DontShowWaitMsg)
            return;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        AppMainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (System.Action)delegate()
        {
            AppMainWindow.pleaseWaitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
    });
}

public void RemoveWaitMsg()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        AppMainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (System.Action)delegate() { AppMainWindow.pleaseWaitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; });
    });
}
```

The problem is that this just doesnt work, I get no errors, just doent update. The only time the UI gets updated is when a confirmation popup is opened between the calling of the set and removing functions.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're calling a background thread only to update the UI message. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to remove `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. But that shouldn't matter, I think. It seems like *you're doing your long running task on the UI thread*. I mean, in order to allow WPF playing animation, you need to execute your operation on a parallel thread, meanwhile the UI thread will play your animation.

So, this code is for setting wait message from any thread:

```
public void SetWaitMsg(string msg)
{
    if (Session.User != null)
        if (Session.User.Configuration.DontShowWaitMsg)
            return;

    AppMainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (System.Action)delegate()
    {
        AppMainWindow.pleaseWaitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    });
}

public void RemoveWaitMsg()
{
    AppMainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (System.Action)delegate() { AppMainWindow.pleaseWaitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; });
}
```

But as Yuval helped me realize, we're not sure if you're doing background task properly. So, assuming you're executing code above on the UI thread, your actual code should be like this:

```
MainWindow.SetWatingMsg("please wait ...");

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLongRunnnigTask());

MainWindow.RemoveWaitingMsg();


public void SetWaitMsg(string msg)
{
    if (Session.User != null && Session.User.Configuration.DontShowWaitMsg)
            return;

    AppMainWindow.pleaseWaitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

public void RemoveWaitMsg()
{
    AppMainWindow.pleaseWaitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: No need to use `Dispatchet.BeginInvoke` if you're on the main thread.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov noone knows for sure if he runs this method on the UI thread or not. He gave us too little code.

Comment: Than you cant assume in your answer that he isn't.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I wasn't assuming, look at the title: Update Main Window from _different thread_

Comment: The different thread may just be the `Task.Factory.StartNew` you removed from the code.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov there's no sense in doing something like this

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am calling from different thread. The Task.Factory.StartNew method was something I have tried but the result remained the same. I wanted to do thing in this way because setting the wait message is something that I have to do many time in the application, in other threads then the ui, snd so I would want to avoid Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLongRunnnigTask()); everytime I want to do this!